# Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN when running in container

Tags: docker, dns, containers, getaddrinfo

I'm having this error in my API when running my docker compose up.
For some reason, the api cannot connect to the bank. Probably DNS error.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
  full-application:
    driver: bridge

services:
  db: 
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres-container
    networks:
      - full-application
    restart: always
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  api:
    build: 
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    networks:
      - full-application
    container_name: node-container
    restart: always
    env_file: ./backend/.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3003:3000"
```

API connection with postgres:

```
const client = new pg.Pool({
    host: 'postgres://db:5432', 
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'mypassword', 
    database: 'docker'
});
```

Error (it is possible to see it through docker logs (container)):

> [nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/index.ts`
> Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres://db:5432
> at /home/node/app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
> errno: -3001,
> code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
> syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
> hostname: 'postgres://db:5432'
> }
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: A repro of your Docker Compose file worked for me. I encourage you to try adding a 3rd service for `adminer`. See the example `docker-compose.yml` on the Postgres container page on DockerHub [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres). You should be able to access `adminer` on the host's port 8080 and configure it to connect to your db. If that doesn't work, it should help you identify the issue. If it does, then the issue lies with your `api` config.

Comment: One thing to note is that e.g. `ports: [5432:5432]"` exposes the `db` service's port 5432 on the host (!) port 5432. You may use this for debugging (e.g. to try to access the Postgres DB from the host) **but** it's likely that you don't want to do this if the `api` service is the only consumer of the db.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for the comment. I managed to solve it. Basically: The API started before the database. depends_on does not wait for the database to start, only the container.
I also cleared image cache.